# Windows 7 Apache 2.4 Virtual Hosts don't work

Tags: windows, apache, localhost, virtualhost

I am trying to have two separate domain names on the same IP address.  I tried restarting Apache and that did not work.  Any ideas?

Below is the virtual host section of my httpd.conf file.

```html
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot H:/Resume
    ServerName http://simonkurtisrhee.ddns.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot H:/MiriWeb/public_html
    ServerName http://miri.ddns.net
</VirtualHost>


ServerRoot "C:/Apache24"

ServerName localhost:80
```

Answer (score 0):

ServerName is host names only. Don't include `http://`

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot H:/Resume
    ServerName simonkurtisrhee.ddns.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot H:/MiriWeb/public_html
    ServerName miri.ddns.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Also those ServerName `hostnames` will have to resolve to an IP available on your machine.